# Can I double the pizza dough recipe for my bread machine

Tags: baking, equipment, dough, pizza

I have a Panasonic SD-ZB2512 bread maker and I like to use it to make pizza dough. It does a good enough job but only makes enough for one pizza at a time. **Can I double the recipe?** I'm pretty sure it would fit but worry the recipe might not be scale-able for other reasons. **Would I be risking  horrible dough or a damaged machine?**

Comment: What does your instruction manual say about max. load?

Comment: They state that it has a capacity of 600g of flour, the normal recipe calls for 300g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to, give the capacity you state in your comment, but it might not mix or rise properly.

You'll have to test, keeping within the capacity limits to protect the machine.  You might end up with bad dough, but it may be receoverable with some extra kneading and proving (though it won't recover to as good as you'd have got in the first place).

You may also have some success with a generic dough program for the amount of flour you want to use -- but again you might have barely-acceptable results, or you might have a complete failure the first time.  You may need to adjust the water content if your dough doesn't work out.

Personally I'd test it but not for guests until you'd perfected it.  I tend to make the standard pizza dough quantity for my machine but roll it out much larger for a thin-based family-size pizza -- another way to make one batch go further.

Comment: Many thanks -- This was very helpful -- I tried it and it was indeed not nearly as good as the recommended quantity. But I may try again with some extra kneading.